# Quitar botones de WPF por defecto

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, wpf

¿alguien sabe qué son y como quitar los botones que se me añaden por defecto al crear un proyecto **WPF**?

Adjunto imagen con los botones a los que me refiero:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En windows forms no me aparece sólo en WPF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Así como las herramientas de desarrollador que ofrecen los navegadores web para inspeccionar el código y averiguar el orden jerárquico de los elementos, estos botones te ayudan a eso mismo en una aplicación `WPF`.

Por ejemplo el primero, al hacer clic, te abre una ventana en el `Visual Studio` con la información del orden jerárquico, el segundo te sirve para seleccionar un elemento en pantalla para así a través del primer botón ubicarlo.

Estos botones se muestran cuando ejecutas la aplicación a partir de `Visual Studio`, cuando compiles y ejecutes el archivo con extensión `.exe` no se mostrarán estos.

Answer (score 3):

Se pueden quitar así:

Ingles:

> Tools –> Options –> Debugging –> General –> Enable UI Debugging Tools
>   for XAML

Español:

> Herramientas -> Opciones -> Depuración -> General -> Habilitar las
>   herramientas de depuración de interfaz usando XAML

Y listo, un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Para quitar los botones de **minimizar**, **maximizar** y **cerrar** de una
ventana en `WPF` se hace lo siguiente:

En la etiqueta principal llama **Window** del `xaml` se le inserta la propiedad `WindowStyle` con valor `None`, quedándo así: `WindowStyle="None"`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí surge un problema! No se puede arrastrar la ventana con el cursor del mouse. Démosle solución a esto.
 A los objetos que queremos que se le aplique la funcionalidad de arrastrar ventana le insertamos en su evento `MouseDown` el siguiente código:

```
 BarTitle.MouseDown += (o, e) => 
 {
     if (o == null) return;
     DragMove();
 };
```

En este caso el objeto se llama **BarTitle**, siempre hay que verificar que la variable `object o` que recive el evento no sea `null`

Comment: Hola lazarok. Esos no son los botones a los que se refiere la pregunta. La pregunta se refiere al pequeño toolbar que aperece automáticamente cuando depuras un proyecto WPF.

Answer (score 0):

Espera mi respuesta les ayude, esto funciona en visual studio 2019

1. ingresa a las `herramientas` en el panel superior (`Tools`) Alt + T(solo en ingles)
2. ingresa a `opciones` (`options`)
3. `Depuración` (`Debugging`)
4. `Recarga Activa` (`Hot Reload`)
5. desactivamos la opcion `Habilitar la barra de herramientas en la aplicación`
   (`enable in app-bar for toolbar`)

> Ingles

[image: Ingles]

> Español

[image: Español]